# Microsoft Bot Framework - Bot goes to sleep. Is there a way to prevent it?

Tags: botframework

My bot based on the bot framework works pretty good. But when I first interact with the bot after a period of inactivity (let's say a day), then the bot seems to take very long time (about 10-45 seconds) to send back its first reply. After that reply the response time is pretty good again.

To me it seems the back-end service goes to some kind of sleep mode and the 1st request wakes it up.

Is there any way to influence this behavior? I concerned about the long initial response time for my users.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using Azure website, see "Always On Support"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure

> Always On. By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time. If your app runs continuous web jobs, you should enable Always On, or the web jobs may not run reliably.

Comment: I have the very same issue. Tried the "Always ON" feature but with no success. On top of the BotFramework I have the QnAMaker. Pls advise

Comment: You could create an Azure function that makes a periodic http request to the bot to keep it alive.

Comment: This seems like a not very nice workaround. Is there any other solution. I tried WAT test but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I'm keeping the bot awake by periodically (every 15min) opening a conversation and sending a first message (activity) to the bot.

**First, I start a conversation:**

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations
Authorization: Bearer SECRET_OR_TOKEN
```

I got the SECRET_OR_TOKEN from the Azure resource: Azure Bot -> channels -> Web Chat -> e.g. Default Site -> Secret Keys

That's what a sample response from the docs looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
{
  "conversationId": "abc123",
  "token": "RCurR_XV9ZA.cwA.BKA.iaJrC8xpy8qbOF5xnR2vtCX7CZj0LdjAPGfiCpg4Fv0y8qbOF5xPGfiCpg4Fv0y8qqbOF5x8qbOF5xn",
  "expires_in": 1800,
  "streamUrl": "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/abc123/stream?t=RCurR_XV9ZA.cwA..."
}
```

link to docs about creating a new conversation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-start-conversation?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#open-a-new-conversation

**Then, I send a simple messsage (activity) as part of the conversation I just started:**

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/{conversation-id-received-from-create-conversation-request}/activities
Authorization: Bearer {token-received-from-create-conversation-request}
Content-Type: application/json
[other headers]

{
    "locale": "en-EN",
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
}
```

You will have to replace the token and conversation Id in the request above. They are both returned in the start a conversation request.

here is a link to the docs about sending an activity to a conversation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-send-activity?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#send-an-activity