# Keeping the bot alive

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

We are building a bot using the MS Bot Framework. Sometimes when the bot is not used, it takes too much time to respond and we get a [500] Internal Server Error. We see this issue when we try to access the bot on our app (we are using Direct Line to interact with the bot).

I've read other answers about making sure the Microsoft Azure setting for application activity is set to "Always On", and we have done this. But as Always on is pinging the root of our bot web app, I think it may not be enough to keep the bot / directline alive...

And I don't have any rewrite rules from http to https preventing the ping request to be successful..

Anybody had this issue?

UPDATE to ask a specific question : How can we make sure that our bot is ALWAYS alive if all the settings explained above do not work ? Should we ping our bot thru the directline framework ?

Comment: not sure why my question is downvoted with -1... Do we have to put the reference of each article we looked at before asking a question ??

Comment: You aren't asking a specific question about a specific problem and you don't show any code or information to help resolve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help Asking if anyone has this issue is open ended and not allowed. Don't make us guess at what you're doing.

Comment: ok, thx ! I have updated my question with your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to send a ping every 15 minutes.  The default code even gives you a place to handle the ping in the message controller

```
else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
{

}
```

please also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822971/microsoft-bot-framework-bot-goes-to-sleep-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-it) as it may work for you and is a very simple solution with no code.

Comment: The link you are referring to is about Always On and we already implemented that. The bot azure website stays alive with this feature but it does not prevent the bot to stop responding after a period of inactivity...

Comment: And I believe that to send a PING to the bot, you need to have a conversation going... So you need to maintain an active conversation to be able to do that, which is a pain if you want to do that thru the Azure Scheduler (for instance Azure function)

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an azure function that pings my service, as I was having this same problem. I have Always On for all my services, and still find the bot going to sleep. With the ping service, it establishes a new conversation, sends the utterance, and then closes after receiving the response. This has seemed to work, but is only a week into practice. Note, I am pinging every five minutes.