# proactively sending messages in skype bot automatically stops

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework, skype

I created an Azure Web App (Bot App), and added to the skype. Also followed the documentation mentioned in (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages) to send (Ad hoc) proactive messages. And I set an *Azure Logic App* to trigger an event which calls my *Bot App's proactively message sending method* via *http post request* to run at every 30 minutes, so that my skype bot will send messages to skype users at every 30 minutes proactively. 
And the bot works absolutely fine with this method.

**But my problem is after some period of time, skype bot automatically stops sending proactive messages.** Most probably it happens when no user sends even a single message to the skype bot for more than 20-30 minutes (when skype bot is idle for more than 20 minutes). If any user sends any message to the skype bot, then again proactive messages works fine when Azure Logic App triggers the event. 
I can't figure out why it automatically stops, please help me with this.

Comment: Do you have some log in this application related to the process and also for exceptions?

Comment: Your bot is going to sleep, try sending a ping activity every 15 minutes or less to your bot to keep it up.

Comment: @vdefeo no i don't have any log

Comment: @JasonSowers can i know why is it going to sleep please? issue in botframework or azure?

Comment: please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822971/microsoft-bot-framework-bot-goes-to-sleep-is-there-a-way-to-prevent-it

Comment: @JasonSowers I did as you suggested. Made azure 'Always On'. And then proactively messaging time is automatically extended up to 24hours (bot works fine for 24hours, previously it worked fine just 20-30mins). But after 24hours, same problem occurred (when no skype user send any message, then proactive messaging stops). Any suggestion why this happens?

Comment: Have you tried sending a `message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping` to the bot periodically?